# Why do some includes in Django need strings, and others variable names?

Tags: python, django, url, urlconf

Referring to the [Django Book, chapter 3](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03.html):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

What determines why one thing is included as a string, and another as regular variable? Why `admin.site.urls` but not `'admin.site.urls'`? All other `include`s are included as strings... I see no logical pattern here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the first pattern (`'mysite.views.home'` -> a view function) is deprecated in 1.8: it led to all kinds of trouble.

As for the rest, it generally works both. `'mysite.foo.urls'` is resolved to include the patterns in the module `mysite.foo.urls`, but `from mysite.foo import urls as foo_urls; include(foo_urls)` works as well. The string-based imports are mostly a historical artifact that hasn't been removed, but it is convenient and doesn't have any real drawbacks as the module is immediately imported (and thus, any `ImportError` is easily traceable to the url config).

`admin.site.urls` is different, because `admin.site.urls` is *not* a module, but `site` is an object and `urls` is an attribute. For that reason, string-based imports of `admin.site.urls` won't work, and you have to use the second method.

As a last note, the warning at the beginning of the Django Book, stating that it is extremely out of date, is outdated. More up-to-date resources, such as the official documentation (one of the best official documentations I know), would be preferable.

Comment: What would you do to call a view there then past dj 1.8? import the view and call it like 
`url(r'^$', view_but_not_as_string, name='home')`?

Comment: Without the include: `from mysite.views import home; ...url(r'^$', home, name='home'),...`. `include()` is only to add other patterns nested in the current pattern.

Answer (score 4):

If you're passing to include() a list of url() instances, then you don't use a string (see [Include() docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#include) and [Including other URLconfs docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)). In your admin urls example, `admin.site.urls` refers to a list of url instances. See the get_urls method in the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py) (which provides the list of url instances referred to by `admin.site.urls`).

```
def get_urls(self):
    ...
    # Admin-site-wide views.
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', wrap(self.index), name='index'),
        url(r'^login/$', self.login, name='login'),
        url(r'^logout/$', wrap(self.logout), name='logout'),
        url(r'^password_change/$', wrap(self.password_change, cacheable=True), name='password_change'),
        url(r'^password_change/done/$', wrap(self.password_change_done, cacheable=True),
            name='password_change_done'),
        url(r'^jsi18n/$', wrap(self.i18n_javascript, cacheable=True), name='jsi18n'),
        url(r'^r/(?P<content_type_id>\d+)/(?P<object_id>.+)/$', wrap(contenttype_views.shortcut),
            name='view_on_site'),
    ]
```

Comment: if I could put 2 green arrows, I'd give you one

Answer (score 3):

You are right this was a little confusing. They changed this in Django 1.8, so now they only support including normal variables.

Read more about this in [Django 1.8 release note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns).

Comment: The link provided is for referencing views, not URLconfs in general

Answer (score 3):

You must to put a path with a string into the function include(). But admin.site.urls is like a string because at the begining of code, you have a import

Answer (score 3):

From the Django 1.8 documentation, include() can take as an argument a module **OR** a module name

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#include

The line

```
from django.contrib import admin
```

imports the admin module.  Thus, it can be used directly as an argument for include.  The other include() methods have string arguments that name other URLconfs.